# Need help setting up doctrine 2 cascade deletes

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am quite confused setting up cascade deletes in Doctrine 2. Here's what my setup looks like

[image]

I want to setup cascading so that I can do something like `$list->getStages()->clear()`

I tried in Stage class

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="TaskProgress", mappedBy="stage", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $taskStages;
```

But that did nothing, I even tried putting the same thing in other classes like List, TaskProgress or Task but nothing seem to work, I may have done it wrong tho ..

Comment: What tool did you use to generate that object diagram? I like it.

Comment: @Arms, I think its MySQL Workbench,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade remove is not used when calling "clear". Its called when you pass the Stage class to EntityManager#remove(), then all TaskProgress entities are also deleted.